# Ionic Capacitor chart.js showing blank on ios device

Tags: android, ios, chart.js, ionic4, capacitor

I swear I have thoroughly searched.

Ionic, (btw, only Capacitor works for ios, and only Cordova for android, -just cordova, or just capacitor won't work for both-, and... some cordova is still needed for ios-capacitor to work, but I was able to make all work nice, and publish in both stores, and working on both devices, though issues may happen depending on the plugins you need... feel free to comment).

Then I added chart.js, and in Android, it´s all ok on device, but when testing on an ios device, charts are blank.
No chart.js code sample needed here, as the code is just the same you can find in a simple google search, it may as well just be copy-paste and works fine as just mentioned.
As close as I've come is to figure it may have something to do with the canvas tag, I simply use

```
<canvas #someCanvas></canvas>
```

but it may be needed to add some other properties to this tag, for it to work on ios device.

Any help/thoughts, please? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js dropped support for older browsers so you might have to pollyfill the resize observer and maby some features.

Source: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/8414

Comment: Thanks a lot, @LeeLenalee, it does look like the chance, but here, I need to humbly state that I've reviewed and still I'm not sure how to use that polyfills.io url in my ionic angular polyfills file. It seems just like a copy-paste issue too, but how?. Please excuse my silly question. I started alone in the wild and I'm still learning.